# Different parse function for different start_urls in Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

Can Scrapy set different parse function for every start_urls?

This is the piece of pseudo-code:

```
    start_urls = [
    "http://111sssssssss.com",
    "http://222sssssssssssss.com",
    "http://333sssssssssss.com",
    "http://444sssssssss.com",
]


def parse_1():
    '''some code, this function will crawl http://111sssssssss.com'''


def parse_2():
    '''some code, this function will crawl http://222sssssssssssss.com'''
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override / implement the `parse_start_url` function and there call `parse_1` or `parse_2` when the `response.url` meets your criteria (in this case it is the right URL).

```
def parse_start_url(response):
    if response.url == 'http://111sssssssss.com':
        parse_1(response)
    if response.url == 'http://222sssssssssssss.com':
        parse_2(response)
```

For more information about `parse_start_url()` read [the documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider.parse_start_url).

Comment: I was think about does Scrapy has build in methd, but your idea is still nice. Thk U