# Crawl Multiple domain with one spider in scrapy and loads domain from db

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am newbie to python word as well as Scrapy.

my requirement is **scrape same data from multiple site or domain**.
I want to fetch Credit card data like Annual fee, APR rate, Card name, card Image from all products of banks from banks its own site.

**As there are many banks and each bank has its own domain so i want to fetch same kind of data from different banks credit cards page.**

i have stored url for banks credit card page in **database** and want to ***crawl those url*** and fetch relative data.

*As I want to fetch same type of data from all sites, i want to use **only single spider for this**.*

**so my questions are:**

1. how can i load url to crawl from db?
2. As bank ***site change***,**structure of website also change**, how can i tell scrapy to use parse method as per bank site or credit card name?

I am very sorry for i cant elaborate my problem cleverly and easily understandable.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: First learn scrapy, create a basic project, and then write some code, and then show us what problem do you face.

Comment: I have created a basic project and works fine for single domain. But i want to crawl multiple domain. just need idea how to tell scrapy to use parse method for specific for url, i know we can use callback method in request param, but any other way for this.

Comment: Can you please give reason for negative down vote on question?

Answer (score 1):

Do following, I have been doing this in my large scale project

```
scraped_link = tldextract.extract(response.url)
if 'website' == scraped_link[1] and 'com' == scraped_link[2]:
    #do domething

if 'website2' == scraped_link[1] and 'net' == scraped_link[2]:
    #do domething

if 'website3' == scraped_link[1] and 'com' == scraped_link[2]:
    #do domething
```

Comment: Thanks for replay.I think you are saying same options as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246864/different-parse-function-for-different-start-urls-in-scrapy, is there any pythonic way or scrapy function for this?

Comment: @VishalPatel pretty much same but he is only checking `response.url` but I am checking only domain.

Comment: Thanks, as you are experience python and scrapy developer any pythonic way for this. it is helpful